# VS2015 RTM Angular2/TypeScript problems

Tags: visual-studio-2015, angular, typescript1.5

**How do I fix the errors being reported by VS2015 below?**

I am using **VS2015 RTM** and I've created a very simple angular 2 web app (as seen on angular.io). 
When I build the solution, I get the following two errors:

- error TS1148: Build: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.

I tried to fix this by using a tsconfig.json but with no joy.

- error TS1219: Build: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning.

I tried to fix this by adding a *TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators* element the csproj file and setting it to true, but it didn't remove the error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does your tsconfig.json look? See [this one](https://github.com/jgainfort/angular2MyApp/blob/master/tsconfig.json) (from another SO user, not mine) and this one [from ngconf2015demo](https://github.com/Microsoft/ngconf2015demo/blob/master/tsconfig.json).

Comment: I run this from the command line: tsc --watch -m commonjs -t es5 --emitDecoratorMetadata --experimentalDecorators your-file.ts

Comment: @EricMartinez my tsconfig.json was correct  but VS2015 RTM doesn't recognize it. Perhaps MS will change this (I hope so) in a future upgrade.

Comment: @TGH Thanks for the suggestion but I wanted VS2015 to transpile the ts file automatically after an edit. It's working now. See posts below.

Answer (score 9):

Same issue here. Found this workaround:

1. Change "Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript) changing/adding the following properties:

> ```
> <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
> <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>True</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
> <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
> ```

2. Add/change the same properties in project file

**Note:** The experimental decorators looks to be enabled only if they are enabled in **both** the files.

Comment: I got mine to work by just changing the csproj file.  I also checked my "Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" file and I don't have the pertinent properties set in that file. Be aware that the csproj file has two areas (one for Debug and one for Release) where you need to make these changes. Perhaps you didn't make them in both places - which is why you needed it in the defaults props file. [?]

Comment: In my case, changing both areas in csproj (in two different vs2015 enterprise installations) was not enough. The strangest thing to me is that the experimentalDeocorator are enable only if they are enable them in both the files. If I remove the entry in the default file or if I set it to false, the csproj configuration is disregarded. If I enable the decorators in the default file they are enabled or not depending on the setting of the csproj. Weird

Comment: You are right!  If I create a project in VS2015 RTM using the template for "TypeScript HTML Application project", then just setting these properties in the csproj seems to suffice. However, if I create a project using the MVC template then I need to set the properties in both places as you indicated.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: not to resurrect an old post or anything, but I tried this in VS2015, and it's still showing property decorators as errors. Any other ideas? O.o

Comment: I faced again the same issue after updating to TypeScript 1.6. VS2015 asked me to upgrade typescript version and after that experimentaldecorators where not more enabled. It turned out that a duplicated configuration typescript section was created in the .csproj for the active configuration

Answer (score 2):

For TS1219 look here: http://dotnetspeak.com/2015/06/angular-2-in-visual-studio-2015-with-typescript

You can set the TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators property to true in the project file.

Comment: FYI - don't forget to set the TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators property in the Debug AND Release areas of the csproj file.  I had put it in the Release area and I was running in Debug mode!